# Access Derived Class Property from static class

Tags: javascript, static

I have this example use-case where I want to access `MyOtherClass.property1` from within a static method of the derived class, but assuming I don't know the derived class name, I only know that it has this particular property.

For a standard class instance invoked with `new` keyword I am able to use `new.target`.

Is there some sort of an equivalent for static?

```
class MyClass{
    static method1(){
        // I want to access MyOtherClass.property1 here 
    }
}

class MyOtherClass extends MyClass{
    static method2(){

    }
}

MyOtherClass.property1 = 1;
MyOtherClass.method1();
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. A method in `MyClass` shouldn't assume that it will be called only in a subclass. What do you expect `MyClass.method1()` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype of `MyOtherClass` points to `MyClass` so it should already be in the prototype chain allowing you to access it directly. Then use `this` to access the calling context which should point to `MyOtherClass` since you are calling it with `MyOtherClass.method1()`:

```js
class MyClass{
    static method1(){
        console.log("method1", this.property1) 
    }
}

class MyOtherClass extends MyClass{
    static method2(){
        console.log(method2)
    }

}
MyOtherClass.property1 = 1;
MyOtherClass.method1()
```